# How to read particular value in msExel file into variable using by Java?

Tags: java, csv

What is a easy way to read specific element from msExel file into variable?

**e.g.** text.xls

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 | <-
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

How to read 10 into variable?

Comment: You need a third party api. May be Apache POI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use an API such as [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/). There are plenty of [good examples](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2002-05/01-qa-0503-excel3.html) available.